# Derby XPLAIN procedures are not available

Tags: database, derby, sql-execution-plan, javadb

I'm working on a Derby Database, but there is no function/procedure regarding XPLAIN PLAN in this database. The procedures are available when I create a new database. Is it possible to create these procedures in a DB?

Comment: Is the database that you are having troubles with, an older database? That is, perhaps it pre-dates the introduction of the XPLAIN functionality? I'm wondering if this is related to upgrade processing?

Comment: Hi Bryan, thank you for replying, yes I'm using an old version of Derby, but even after upgrading it using upgrade=true in the connection string, nothing really changed! still these procedures are missing.